# Error using DialogflowPHP: How do i use Dialogflow PHP?

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings::load(): 
Argument #2 ($clientConfig) must be of type array, null given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/wordpress/pruebaDialogFlow/wp-content/themes/pruebaDialogFlow/vendor/google/gax/src/GapicClientTrait.php on line 256 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/wordpress/pruebaDialogFlow/wp-content/themes/pruebaDialogFlow/vendor/google/gax/src/RetrySettings.php:313 Stack trace: 
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/wordpress/pruebaDialogFlow/wp-content/themes/pruebaDialogFlow/vendor/google/gax/src/GapicClientTrait.php(256): Google\ApiCore\RetrySettings::load('google.cloud.di...', NULL, false) 
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/wordpress/pruebaDialogFlow/wp-content/themes/pruebaDialogFlow/vendor/google/cloud-dialogflow/src/V2/Gapic/SessionsGapicClient.php(740): Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\Gapic\SessionsGapicClient->setClientOptions(Array) 
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/wordpress/pruebaDialogFlow/wp-content/themes/pruebaDialogFlow/index.php(12): Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\Gapic\SessionsGapicClient->__construct(Array) 
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/wordpress/pruebaDialogFlow/wp-includes/template-loader.php(106): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...') 
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/wordpress/pruebaDialogFlow/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/opt/lampp/htdo...') 
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/wordpress/pruebaDialogFlow/index.php(17): require('/opt/lampp/htdo...') 
#6 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/work/wordpress/pruebaDialogFlow/wp-content/themes/pruebaDialogFlow/vendor/google/gax/src/RetrySettings.php on line 313
```

My code:
`require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; $sessionClient = new Google\Cloud\Dialogflow\V2\SessionsClient();?>`

I just installed DialogFlow and I cannot use any of the functions.

I'm trying to use the php library of dialogflow

Comment: check variable `$clientConfig` It asking to be an array but you set it as null.